# Кросплатформенная P2P библиотека

Tags: objective-c, c, java, p2p, c++

Есть ли P2P библиотека или фреймворк позволяющие организовать взаимодействие устройств на различных ОС?
А для этого библиотека/фреймворк должнs иметь вариации на следующих языках:
Java
C++
Objective-C
Есть ли такие библиотеки/фреймворки?

Answer (score 1):

Может быть что-то вроде [Thrift](http://thrift.apache.org/)?